# Trying to lauch Appcelerator "Appcelerator CLI is currently installing or upgrading"

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I was using the appcelerator and it asked me to upgrade, after this, the program was not responding, I closed it while the program was installing an update and when I tried to launch again, the program returned an error:
"Appcelerator CLI is currently installing or upgrading" [...]

Now I can't open the appcelerator.. and there aren't any process running for I can close and stop the "download"(if there is some download in process).

I don't know if there is some download in process and neither your progress...

Comment: Better try to install a fresh Studio by deleting the previous one as you closed the program in between. And after doing a fresh install, try to update everything before creating anything.

Comment: does `appc setup` work from CLI?

Comment: No, I couldn't open the IDE.
I'm sorry, I'm new in appcelerator. 

But I found a way to resolve.
 I deleted  ~/.appcelerator /.installing file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to resolve. 
Just delete ~/.appcelerator /.installing file

Answer (score 0):

The problem is about Appcelerator Command Line . Make sure that you nstall the Appcelerator Command Line properly .
Follow the steps to Install the Appcelerator Command Line .
1. Ensure that you have Node.JS installed
node --version
If it works, you will see a version such as v0.10.37.
2. Install the Appcelerator CLI
sudo npm install appcelerator -g
3. After installation, you need to run setup to kick things off.
appc setup
Thanks
Pavel